# Using TSQL Rank Functions to create Max and Min change dates for a table with Effective Dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ranking

I have a series of changes in a table, but in many cases multiple rows exist though no changes within the date range -- and some groupings exist multiple times throughout the series.  Example is more than one rows could exist with From and To dates, but no data changes actually occurred. I need to group these together and find the max and min FromDate and ToDate.  Below is an example I built using test data:

[image]

Trying to find some way to do this using ranking functions to collapse this down to something like this:

[image]

I'm not able to find a good way of doing this.  This is in MS SQL 2019 and below is code to recreate this example for testing.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
PersonID INTEGER,
FullName NVARCHAR(50),
Department NVARCHAR(50),
Room NVARCHAR(50),
FromDate DATE,
ToDate DATE);

INSERT INTO #Test
(PersonID,FullName,Department,Room,FromDate,ToDate)
VALUES
(1,'Jack Smith','Sales','101','2000-01-01','2000-03-02'),
(1,'Jack Smith','Sales','101','2000-03-03','2000-07-01'),
(1,'Jack Smith','Sales','104','2000-07-02','2000-07-05'),
(1,'Jack Smith','Sales','104','2000-07-06','2000-07-29'),
(1,'Jack Smith','Sales','104','2000-07-30','2000-09-05'),
(1,'Jack Smith','Sales','101','2000-09-06','2000-12-02'),
(1,'Jack Smith','Sales','101','2000-12-03','2001-04-02'),
(1,'Jack Smith','Marketing','101','2001-04-03','2001-08-01'),
(1,'Jack Smith','Marketing','101','2001-08-02','2002-01-02'),
(1,'Jack Smith','Sales','104','2002-01-03','2002-04-02');
```

I tried using max and min on the From and To dates with groupings, but this combines grouping together that shouldn't be, for example the rows with Dept Sales and Room 101 should be two distinct lines, but using groupings alone combines them:

```
SELECT PersonID,
       FullName,
       Department,
       Room,
       MIN(FromDate) AS FromDate,
       MAX(ToDate) AS ToDate
FROM #test
GROUP BY PersonID,
       FullName,
       Department,
       Room
```

This results in this which is not correct:

[image]

Can someone give pointers on how to get this using TSQL?  I tried various rank and dense_rank functions to get this set, but nothing seemed to work.  Seems simple enough, but the solution escapes me.  Thank you.

Comment: This looks to be a classic Gap-and-Islands.   Take a peek at https://bertwagner.com/posts/gaps-and-islands/

Comment: There are no gaps in the dates (or if there are it's a flaw in my example).  The issue is I can't find a way to create a distinct rank on each grouping with the FromDate for order when the groupings are not totally distinct.  In the example it's combing two groupings into one with no regard to date.... yet if I add the date to the Partition By in the rank function this makes every row distinct.  

I'll review the gaps and islands article further to see how I can use it, but if you or someone more familiar could create a query example using the sample table, I posted I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Gaps-and-Islands is more than just dates.   It can include any intersection of data/elements

Comment: Problem is the ranking functions combine the matching partitions and aren't keeping them distinct.  Even using the gap and island examples I'm not able to get around this.  Partition By combines all the same groupings even if I add the Order By in there - this order by seems to be applied inside the partition and not outside which would be needed to keep the partitions distinct.

Comment: `select PersonID,FullName,Department,Room, min(FromDate) as FromDate, max(ToDate) as ToDate from
(  select *, sum(addone) over(partition by PersonID,FullName,Department,Room order by FromDate,ToDate rows unbounded preceding) as grp from ( select *, 
      case when FromDate <= dateadd(day, 1, max(ToDate) 
  over(partition by PersonID,FullName,Department,Room 
  order by FromDate,ToDate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)) then 0 else 1  end as addone from #Test ) as r
) as g group by PersonID,FullName,Department,Room,grp
order by PersonID,FullName,Department,Room,FromDate;`

Answer (score 1):

I misread which was the desired results.  Here is a corrected option without the room cheat

```
 Select PersonID
      ,FullName
      ,Department
      ,Room   
      ,FromDate = min(FromDate)
      ,ToDate   = max(ToDate)
 From (
        Select * 
              ,Grp = row_number() over (order by FromDate)
                    -row_number() over (partition by PersonID,Department,Room Order by FromDate)
         from #Test
      ) A
 Group By PersonID
      ,FullName
      ,Department
      ,Room
      ,Grp
 Order By min(FromDate)
```

**Results**

[image]